# How to set admin menu inside different module?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to set admin multiple module menu in one custom menu. for ex. in below image i want to set Banner slider inside the Blog menu. when i open the blog menu i can show here Banner slider menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Menus are created either by `adminhtml.xml` or by `config.xml` to make changes of menu you need to follow the following steps.

1) Find in Blog module which file is used to create menu.

2) Copy the nodes which is used for creating a **Manage comment** which contains `<title>` and `<sort_order>` and `<action>` node and use the same for creating a Banner slider menu.

3) Assign proper action to Banner slider menu.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: its not working for me

Comment: have u able to find a xml file of menu ?

Comment: yes i got it and  menu got displayed but when i click on the link i got 404 error

Comment: when you get a 404 error on which page you are redirecting is it on front end side or in admin ? also either update a question with system.xml of Banner slider and your menu xml or upload some where and send a link on comment.

Comment: You might be making some mistakes in action.